# Function input allows different types

Tags: java

I want to write a function that allows multiple input types:

i.e.

```
public void func(TYPE variable) {
  if (variable instanceof String)
    //do string stuff
  else if (variable instanceof double)
    //do double stuff
}
```

What do I have to declare the type as? Do I have to use generics?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.lang.Object and use instanceof to check the type and do the operation.

```
public void func(Object variable) {
  if (variable instanceof String)
    //do string stuff
  else if (variable instanceof double)
    //do double stuff
}
```

More on generics and using it please see

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html

Comment: I tried that actually and when I use `variable.compareTo(String)` is says it's a `String` function and not an `Object` function.

Comment: Cast it before calling the compareTo ((String) o).compareTo(otherString).

Answer (score 1):

You can create the same function for each type of parameter you need. The function to call will be deduced by the type of the parameter :

```
public void func(String string) {...}
public void func(double double) {...}
```

Comment: The point is that I want to create one function though. Thanks.